# Is this mathematically correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you say that $\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{r_1}{r_2}$ based on these results:

[image]

I'm trying to describe the relationship shown in the table between two resistors with respect to voltage ($v_1 + v_2 = v_3$)

Comment: The relationship doesn't hold exactly. But if your voltage measurements are only accurate to 0.5V, say, then it is possible that the relationship holds. That's why experimenters give error bars when they publish results. Do you have some estimates of your uncertainty?

Comment: @Dan Piponi I don't have estimates of the uncertainty, but I know for a fact that yes, some inaccuracies are present. Can you say that what I said is mathematically correct? What do you mean by that it doesn't 'exactly' hold? How off are we talking about?

Comment: Well $v_1/v_2=13/15$ but $r_1/r_2=1$ for row 1. But suppose there are errors up to 10% in your voltage measurements, so, eg. $v_1$ is actually 2.8 and $v_2$ is actually 2.8, etc., then the relationship might hold exactly.

Answer (score 0):

To within measurement errors it appears correct.  Note that $v_1+v_2=v_3$ is not exactly satisfied by your table.  It looks like you have two resistors in series connected across $v_3$ and you are measuring the voltage across each one.  You would expect $v_1=v_3\frac {r_1}{r_1+r_2}$ and $v_2=v_3\frac {r_2}{r_1+r_2}$, which does lead to $\frac {v_1}{v_2}=\frac {r_1}{r_2}$ in each circuit.

Comment: 100% correct spot on. thanks